# Special mouse events in a browser: wheel, right-click?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, sample, mousewheel, right-click

Google maps is an impressive display of what you can do with JavaScript and Ajaxy-goodness.  Even my mouse scroll wheel and right-click works to provide specific functionality.

In the standard HTML spec, I don't see an `onmouserightclick` event or similar basic JavaScript handling for the mouse wheel.  Maybe I am looking in the wrong places.

I presume these events are browser and platform-specific (or "sensitive" instead of specific).  And am wondering what the basic, plain HTML and JavaScript are needed to exploit these events, in ALL browsers.

Naturally, when designing a site these features have to be extra since some people still use the one-button mouse.

How to I use events with the mouse wheel and right-click?  I'm looking for sample code.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the jQuery code guys!  The system-developer in me still has questions and doubts though.  Mainly I'm concerned about platform-limitations that would seem to apply here.  Is there a browser that some of these features don't work in?  Does the mouse wheel up and down events also allow for mouse wheel click events?  I would just expect there to be some limitation out there and am wondering if it's officially documented.  I want to know how it works at a low level.  I am glad to see it is easy in jQuery, another reason for me to get into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Mouse Wheel***: 
 ol' no-jquery-or-prototype-library method: [here](http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/)

Prototype method: [Here](http://www.ogonek.net/mousewheel/demo.html)

JQuery method: [Here](http://www.ogonek.net/mousewheel/jquery-demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, it's extremely simple to do things with the right click menu :

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    alert("You right clicked!");
    return false; //disable the context menu
});
```

Otherwise, you can use this script, provided by quirskmode:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#link6

As for the mouse wheel, this a great script that I've used in the past:

http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 1):

You said cross-browser so you must mean jQuery :P

http://www.ogonek.net/mousewheel/jquery-demo.html

http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook_files/68/demo/

I bet you can find JavaScript that do that, but I think its always better to go with component(or plugin) because it could have bugs(or maybe cross-browser bugs) and the person that made it would get an email from somebody that is using that and fix it. With pure JavaScript, you always should check it in every version of every browser.

Comment: The question asks for "basic, plain HTML and Javascript". Perhaps we are primarily interested in how it actually works rather than seeing yet another advert for jQuery.

Comment: so why cross-browser? if you disagree with using jquery could you please post it how to do it in every browser?